# Alias the base table in Liquibase valueComputed

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

My problem is the following. I have two tables, let's say `A` and `B`. I'd like to merge `A` and `B` tables together.

Both tables have the following columns (primary keys):

- `transaction_id`
- `group_id`
- `leaf_id`

In addition, `B` has two columns that I'd like to move to table `A`:

- `representation`
- `timestamp`

I created the following changeset in Liquibase:

```
<update tableName="A">
            <column name="representation" valueComputed="
                (SELECT btable.representation
                FROM B btable
                WHERE btable.transaction_id = transaction_id
                AND btable.group_id = group_id
                AND btable.leaf_id = leaf_id)
            "/>
            <column name="timestamp" valueComputed="
                (SELECT btable.timestamp
                FROM B btable
                WHERE btable.transaction_id = transaction_id
                AND btable.group_idx = group_id
                AND btable.leaf_idx = leaf_id)
            "/>
</update>
```

So this doesn't work because table `A` has no alias and `btable.transaction_id = transaction_id` will be interpreted as `btable.transaction_id = btable.transaction_id`.

My question is: Is there a way to alias the **base** table in a `valueComputed` SQL?

I know this is possible to do with `<sql></sql>` in Liquibase but I'd like to avoid using raw SQL if possible.

I'm using Postgres btw.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this so I just ended up using raw SQL in the liquibase changeset like this:

```
<sql>
    UPDATE A
    SET
    custom_representation = (
        SELECT btable.representation
        FROM B btable
        WHERE btable.transaction_id = transaction_id
        AND btable.group_id = group_id
        AND btable.leaf_id = leaf_id
    ),
    timestamp = (
        SELECT btable.timestamp
        FROM B btable
        WHERE btable.transaction_id = transaction_id
        AND btable.group_idx = group_id
        AND btable.leaf_idx = leaf_id
    );
</sql>
```